# Finding counterexample for conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If there is $\Omega$ -a sample space, and $A,B \subset\Omega$ events 
such that $P(A|B)>P(A)$ I need to find counterexample such that $P(B)<P(B|A)$ is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$
$$\frac{P(A|B)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B|A)}{P(B)}$$

Now, if $P(A|B)>P(A) \Rightarrow \frac{P(A|B)}{P(A)}>1$

So using Bayes Theorem, this implies that

$$ \frac{P(B|A)}{P(B)}>1 \Rightarrow P(B|A)>P(B)$$

So it will be true.